# Highchart series from JSON array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, highcharts

I am currently doing a web application where I am trying to pass data from a servlet to a JSP so that it can be used in a Highchart. I am creating a JSON array of dynamic objects and I am passing it to my JSP using AJAX. An example JSON array looks like this:

```
[{"data":[2,4,6,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"name":"DESIGN"},
{"data":[1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"name":"COLOUR"}]
```

I want each of those arrays to be used as a HighChart series, where `"name"` is the name of the series and `"data"` is an array representing monthly sales. After reading tons of examples, I am still unsuccessfully trying to parse the array from my AJAX success function with something along the lines of:

```
$.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url : '/InventoryManagement/dashboardData',
            datatype : 'json',
            success : function(data) {
                var dataObj = JSON.parse(data);
                var seriesArr = new Array();
                $.each(dataObj, function(key, d) {
                    var series = {
                        name : key,
                        data : []
                    };
                    series.key = key;
                    series.d = d;

                    seriesArr.push(series);
                });


                $(function () {
                    var options = {
                        chart : {
                            renderTo : 'overallSales',
                            type : 'column'
                        },
                        title : {
                            text : 'Overal Unit Sales'
                        },
                        xAxis : {
                            categories : [ 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul',
                                    'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec' ]
                        },
                        yAxis : {
                            title : {
                                text : 'Units sold'
                            }
                        },
                        series : seriesArr

                    };
                    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
                });
            }
```

I know I am not passing the data in the `$.each` properly, but this is the first time I'm working with AJAX, JSON or Highcharts, so please tell me how to fix this!

Comment: Have you recieved ajax response correctly? I mean dataObj

Comment: Yes, `[{"data":[2,4,6,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"name":"DESIGN"},{"data":[1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"name":"COLOUR"}]` is returned from an `alert(data)` call in the success function.

Comment: ok..Then you have problem in how it represent in bar chart? am I right?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to parse the `dataObj` inside `seriesArr`, which is passed to the HighCharts series, but I am struggling to populate the `series` array in the correct way.

Comment: please go through my answer, Have you got my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Overal Unit Sales'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: [ 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul',
                    'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec' ],
                title: {
                    text: null
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Value',
                    align: 'high'
                },
                labels: {
                    overflow: 'justify'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: 'unit'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                bar: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: -40,
                y: 80,
                floating: true,
                borderWidth: 1,
                backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'),
                shadow: true
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: dataObj
        });
    });
```

container is chart parent element id that where you place your chart

just add your dataObj into series option in Highchart.In your code you didn't mentions where is to placed.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ksmofjhp/)

Comment: Oh, I didn't know I could just pass the dataObj directly to the series! Thank you so much!